# Copy files from text file in directory

Tags: python, shutil, os.walk

I am attempting to move pdf files from sub-directories in a folder. This code works and moves all pdfs found. I would like to only move pdf files that match number from a text file using this code:

```
with open('LIST.txt', 'r') as f:
    myNames = [line.strip() for line in f]
    print myNames
```

Full code:

```
import os
import shutil

with open('LIST.txt', 'r') as f:
    myNames = [line.strip() for line in f]
    print myNames

dir_src = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\oldfolder"
dir_dst = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\newfolder"

for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_src):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".pdf"):
            shutil.copy( os.path.join(dirpath, file), dir_dst )
```

example of text file content:

```
111111
111112
111113
111114
```

Comment: You only want to move files which match (in what way? file name? content?) from a text file (I assume you mean your `'LIST.txt'`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a `set` instead of a list here so lookup will be faster:

```
myNames = {line.strip() for line in f}
```

Then for the filter, I assume that `myNames` must match the basename (minus extension) of your file(s). So instead of:

```
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
        shutil.copy( os.path.join(dirpath, file), dir_dst )
```

check the extension and if the basename minus extension belongs to your previously created set:

```
    bn,ext = os.path.splitext(file)
    if ext == ".pdf" and bn in myNames:
        shutil.copy( os.path.join(dirpath, file), dir_dst )
```

To match the filename with a substring within `myNames`, you cannot rely on the `in` method. You can do:

```
    if ext == ".pdf" and any(s in file for s in myNames):
```